# How can I delete spaces between custom widgets and fit widgets in listview.builder in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I am making a card game with flutter. I want to show my cards in contiguous order on the playing table. I made a custom widget for cards and put them in a listview.builder. Between cards are occurring spaces and cards are not fitting to the screen. I searched for this problem internet but I did not fix it. Where is my fault? Can you help me?

CardViewWidget:

```
Widget cardViewWidget(PlayingCard card) {
return Container(
  height: 80.0,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 5,
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        _returnAssetUrl(card),
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);}
```

build:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                oppoHand[0].cardType.toString() +
                    oppoHand[0].cardSuit.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              Text(
                oppoHand[1].cardType.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              Text(
                oppoHand[2].cardType.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              Text(
                oppoHand[3].cardType.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              Text(
                oppoHand[4].cardType.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text("Score: " + oppoScore.toString()),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: groundDeck.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Text(groundDeck[index].cardType.toString());
              },
            ),
          ]),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text("Score: " + myScore.toString()),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 100.0,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: myHand.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _clickedCard(index);
                        });
                      },
                      child: cardViewWidget(myHand[index]),
                    );
                  }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);}}
```

This is my screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSpfn.png)

Comment: Try using mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min for Row() | If that doesn't work remove the Row() and make the ListView.builder the direct child of Container().

Comment: @ArshShaikh I tried them. When I made mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min for Row(),nothing happened. When I removed the Row(), the width error fixed but did not solve spaces and fit the custom card widgets on the screen.

Comment: Only the ListView.builder() should have done it, because it doesn't spread it's items except when a padding is provided. I guess it's the FlatButton() causing the issues. Replace the FlatButton() with an InkWell() or GestureDetector()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this. This will solve your issue!

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  oppoHand[0].cardType.toString() + oppoHand[0].cardSuit.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
                Text(
                  oppoHand[1].cardType.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
                Text(
                  oppoHand[2].cardType.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
                Text(
                  oppoHand[3].cardType.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
                Text(
                  oppoHand[4].cardType.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Text("Score: " + oppoScore.toString()),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: groundDeck.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Text(groundDeck[index].cardType.toString());
                },
              ),
            ]),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Text("Score: " + myScore.toString()),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100.0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: ListView.builder(
                 scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                 shrinkWrap: true,
                 itemCount: myHand.length,
                 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                   return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                       setState(() {
                         _clickedCard(index);
                       });
                     },
                     child: cardViewWidget(myHand[index]),
                   );
                 }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}}
```

Comment: This solve fixed the width error, the custom widgets are scrollable now but did not solve spaces and fit the custom card widgets on the screen. I do not want to custom widgets scrollable

Comment: means you want no spaces between cards? and you don't want that horizontal scroll on that list?

Comment: Yes, I want the cards to be as close to one as possible and fit exactly on the screen. Think card games, for example, Uno, Heartstone vs. Think this game's owned card board. But think straight-lined cards version.

Comment: Check the updated code. It has no spaces now between the cards. Just replaced FlatButton with GestureDetector.